# Where can I find Go runtime goroutines spec?

Tags: multithreading, go, goroutine

After running a rather simple Go program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    sigs := make(chan os.Signal)

    signal.Notify(sigs, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)

    fmt.Printf("awaiting signal at %d\n", os.Getpid())
    <-sigs
    fmt.Printf("\nexiting\n")
}
```

I can observe the following threads being created on my system (found by `top -H` to list threads aside processes):

```
 3949 USER    20   0    3232   1400   1032 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 goroutines1
 3950 USER    20   0    3232   1400   1032 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 goroutines1
 3951 USER    20   0    3232   1400   1032 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 goroutines1
 3952 USER    20   0    3232   1400   1032 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 goroutines1
 3953 USER    20   0    3232   1400   1032 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 goroutines1
```

Where `PID 3949` is the main thread.

Where can I find the spec/information about the other 4 threads being run by Go runtime?

Comment: The comments at the beginning of [`runtime/proc.go`](https://golang.org/src/runtime/proc.go) might provide a starting point for you. What are you hoping to learn, out of curiosity?

Comment: @TimCooper I just want to get some insight into what exactly is Go runtime doing: I know that there is GC and goroutine scheduler running but what more?

Comment: There's no such spec because [The spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec) defines the language, not an implementation. Currently two full-blown implementations of Go exist: the reference one, known as "gc", the one you're probably using, and another one, which is a part of GCC. The language implementation must adhere to that spec but are free to do that in whatever way they see fit.